# Prove $0<\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{|a_{k}|}\prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^{n+1}\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k}-a_{j}}\le\sqrt{2}$

Tags: inequality

> let  $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n+1}$ be a sequence of distinct non-zero real numbers with
> $$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}a^2_{j}=1,~~~\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}a_{j}=0$$
> show this
> $$0<\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{|a_{k}|}\prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^{n+1}\dfrac{a_{k}}{a_{k}-a_{j}}\le\sqrt{2}\tag{1}$$

I found the equality on the right-hand side when $n=1$.But I can't prove this inequality $(1)$.First of all, this inequality is a bit like  Lagrange's interpolation formula  [Prove $1 + \sum_{i=0}^n(\frac1{x_i}\prod_{j\neq i}(1+\frac1{x_j-x_i}))=\prod_{i=0}^n(1+\frac1{x_i})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500139/prove-1-sum-i-0n-frac1x-i-prod-j-neq-i1-frac1x-j-x-i-prod-i?rq=1), I'm going to try to prove it using  Lagrange's interpolation formula but can't it

Comment: Isn't Lagrange interpolation formula for polynomials?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac 1{|a_k|}\prod_{j\ne k,j\le n} \dfrac{a_k}{a_k-a_j}\le \sqrt 2$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac 1{|a_k|}\prod_{j\ne k,j\le n+1} \dfrac{a_k}{a_k-a_j}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac 1{|a_k|(a_k-a_{n+1})}\prod_{j\ne k,j\le n} \dfrac{a_k}{a_k-a_j}+\dfrac 1{|a_{n+1}|}\prod_{j\ne n+1}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}-a_j}$.

The first part is $\le \dfrac {\sqrt2}{a_l-a_{n+1}}$ whence $l$ is such that $a_l-a_{n+1}$ is minimal among all $1\le l\le n$.

Comment: Now posted on MO, too: [How prove this Webb inequality?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/380923)